# Can I convert a gamestop card to wallet funds on Play Station Network?

Tags: psn

Is it possible to do this without going to gamestop in person and buying the card?

Comment: What you're asking is a little unclear - could you elaborate?

Comment: @Kareen The OP has some GameStop store credit. They would like to buy a PlayStation Network gift card, but would prefer to do so online without having to go to a store and buy a physical card.

Comment: It depends on how the store credit is stored. If it's on their GameStop card, then no they have to go to the store to convert it. If they have it somehow tied to an on-line GameStop membership (like the PowerUp Rewards program). Then they may be able to do this all from within the GameStop website.

Not enough data though to really work through this question.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to do that and it would not work. I went to GameStop in person and they said they could not do that in store and that they have no control over what happens on the website because the GameStop store branch of the franchise have control over PowerUpRewards.com. GameStop.com is basically a whole different branch of the GameStop franchise know as the online branch of the GameStop franchise. The rest is a bit hazy but you should get the idea.

It's impossible to convert a GameStop gift card into wallet Funds for the PlayStation Network.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this [$10 gift card](http://www.gamestop.com/dlc/playstation-store-10-gift-card/110529) or this [$20 gift card](http://www.gamestop.com/dlc/playstation-store-20-gift-card/110207), and just redeem them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can use a gamestop card and buy a $10, $20 or $50 PSN card online, and they email you the PSN code.  I'd like to see the availability to be able to enter any denomination you wish.  For example, I have a $25 gamestop card.  I'd like to enter my own denomination of a $25 psn card.  I think I can get this exact amount at the store, but I'd like to see it be done online as well.

Comment: It looks like you can also get a $75 and $100 PSN card as well.

Comment: As far as gamestop credits go.  It depends on if they are monetary or gamestop points.  If they are monetary, then gamestop should be able to convert it to a psn card for you at the store.  As to if you can do that online or not, I haven't seen.  If they are points, then sometimes they have the availability to redeem points for gift cards.  You just have to look in the rewards section.

Comment: In fact, you can turn in your rewards points for gift cards.  5,000 points for a $5 Reward Certificate
10,000 points for a $10 Reward Certificate
15,000 points for a $15 Reward Certificate